# Bulk delete of data transfers in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

over time, many different people have created a test transfer in our demo project and never cleaned it up.  I would love to bulk delete all transfers.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built something similar on [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows).

Essentially you need a Workflow that will do the steps for you start with [BigQuery Data Transfer API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest) and issue a few commands:

- get a list of transfer configs
- loop through them
- issue a delete API call for them

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest

My code was to cleanup Cloud Workflows (you need to adapt a little bit this one with the Transfer Service API calls)

```
#cloud workflow to cleanup 
main:
  steps:
    - initialize:
        assign:
          - project: "marton-data"
          - location: "us-central1"
    - getList:
        call: WorkflowsList
        args:
          project: ${project}
          location: ${location}
        result: items
    - loopItems:
        call: WorkflowListLoopItems
        args:
          items: ${items}
        result: res
    - final:
        return: ${res}
WorkflowsList:
  params: [project,location]
  steps:
    - list:
        call: googleapis.workflows.v1.projects.locations.workflows.list
        args:
            parent: ${"projects/"+project+"/locations/"+location}
            pageSize: 100
        result: listResult
    - documentFound:
        return: ${listResult.workflows}
WorkflowDelete:
  params: [name]
  steps:
    - delete:
        call: googleapis.workflows.v1.projects.locations.workflows.delete
        args:
            name: ${name}
        result: deleteResult
    - logStep: 
        call: sys.log
        args:
          text: ${"Calling "+name+" \r\n Results returned "+json.encode_to_string(deleteResult)}
    - deleteDone:
        return: ${deleteResult}
WorkflowListLoopItems:
  params: [items]
  steps:
    - init:
        assign:
          - i: 0
          - result: ""
    - check_condition:
        switch:
          - condition: ${items[i].name=="projects/marton-data/locations/us-central1/workflows/workflow_cleanup"}
            next: assign_loop
          - condition: ${len(items) > i}
            next: iterate
        next: exit_loop
    - iterate:
        steps:
          - process_item:
              call: WorkflowDelete
              args:
                name: ${items[i].name}
              result: result
          - assign_loop:
              assign:
                - i: ${i+1}
        next: check_condition
    - exit_loop:
        return: ${result}
logMessage:
  params: [collection]
  steps:
    - log:
        call: http.post
        args:
            url: https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:write
            auth:
                type: OAuth2
            body:
                entries:
                    - logName: ${"projects/" + sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID") + "/logs/workflow_logger"}
                      resource:
                        type: "audited_resource"
                        labels: {}
                      jsonPayload: ${collection}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the [bq](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_rm) tool and bash.

To list the transfer_configs in a location

```bash
bq ls --transfer_config=true --transfer_location=europe-west3
```

Filtering on dataSourceIds is also possible.

```bash
bq ls --transfer_config=true --transfer_location=europe-west3 --filter="dataSourceIds:cross_region_copy"
```

To get a list of resources for deleting, select just the resource name from the output.

```bash
bq ls --transfer_config=true --transfer_location=europe-west3 --filter="dataSourceIds:cross_region_copy" --format=json |  jq -r ' .[].name'
```

And delete. Are you sure? Note the --force flag.

```bash
for item in $( bq ls --transfer_config=true --transfer_location=europe-west3 --filter="dataSourceIds:cross_region_copy" --format=json |  jq -r ' .[].name'); do
   bq rm --force --transfer_config=true $item
done
```